# php running on IIS 8 WIN 2012 Server "IS" pointing to correct php.ini but extension_dir is still pointing to "C:\PHP"

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012

Now you're going to say, "Well, Pete, Google it because it's really simple..."  OK, I agree. So here are my givens:

**GIVENS:**

1. php is running on IIS 8 on a WIN 2012 Server box
2. php is running nicely
3. MYSQL is running nicely
4. Handler mappings are perfect
5. I have gone here http://www.peterguy.com/php/install_IIS6.html and followed this to the "T"

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to set my extension_dir but for the life of me, although it's POINTING to the "D:\php\ext" directory, the PHP.INI still and always shows: "C:\PHP" no matter what I do.

Finally, I'm running php in IIS with phpmanager very nicely.  I've been racking my brain for days... I need to install CONCRETE 5 CMS and e107 CMS.

The errors I get for concrete is:

[image]

The two warnings are: PDO extension is NOT loaded - A direct result of the extension_dir =  not pointing to the correct place and Concrete 5 requires GD Library 2.0.1; again a direct result of the extention_dir =    not pointing correctly.

Please help....

Thanks

Comment: Err, you're running Windows Server 2012, IIS 8, and you decided to follow a Windows 2003, IIS 6. how-to? In your php.ini, set your `extension_dir`, in my case: `extension_dir = "./ext"`. For you it must be something like `extension_dir = "D:/php/ext"`. In your FastCGI handler, make sure you have a `PHPRC` environment variable set up pointing to your php.ini location. See https://www.saotn.org/php-wincache-on-iis/ for some more information about setting up PHP and handlers.

Comment: YOU DA MAN!!! Thank you Jan. Well, unless Jan is not of Male Gender than YOU DA WO-MAN! LOL. Thank you either way